# writing subquery in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

How can I find in SQL SERVER if counts where Name like '%Server%' and Status = 1 is greater than 5.

```
Name Status
Server1 0
Server2 1
Server3 1
Server4 1
Server5 1
Server6 1
Server7 0
Database1 1
DataBase2 0
```

I know how to write separate queries but do not know how to combine them.

```
SELECT Name,Status FROM [dbo].[Jobs_Status](nolock) where Name like 'Server%'
```

Thanks
R

Comment: `status = 1 is greater than 5`? Huh? `status = 1 > 5` -> `status = false`?

Comment: I would recommend to not use NOLOCK. Are you aware of the ramifications of that hint?

Comment: @SeanLange, let me know if i am right- when u say nolock, other DML statements can modify the table.

Comment: NOLOCK means that it will ignore any locks on the table by other processes. It can and will at some point return missing and/or duplicate rows. Take a look at this article. It explains it in great detail. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx

Comment: But if you are going to use query hints you need to also use the WITH keyword. That keyword is not going to be optional in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use T-SQL to check if the count is greater than 5 and perform some other action, as in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/137c2/4).

```
IF ((select count(*) from jobs where name like 'Server%' and Status = 1) >= 5)
BEGIN
    SELECT 1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like

```
SELECT [Status Count Greater Than 5] = case when Count(*) > 5 then 1 else 0 end
FROM [dbo].[Jobs_Status]
where Name like 'Server%' and Status = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
SELECT Name  
FROM [dbo].[Jobs_Status](nolock) 
where Name like 'Server%' 
 and Status=1
and 
(select count(*) from  [dbo].[Jobs_Status](nolock) where Name like 'Server%' and Status=1) >5
```